# Adobe After Effects layer not snapping sometimes

Tags: layers, adobe-after-effects, snapping

I have recorded the problem here:
https://vimeo.com/454995903

I'm holding down Shift key, and trying to move the layer to snap to the beginning of the other layer.

As you can see, I narrowed down the problem to the text layer above it, it seems like the text layer's opacity key frames are causing this issue.

How do I fix this? Every time this happens, I have to zoom in maximally on the timeline and move the layer frame by frame to get the layer adjusted to the beginning of the other layer, because I don't know which other layer is causing this.

Answer (score 1):

This might happen when the keyframe is not exactly on the frame. To fix that, just drag the keyframe until it snaps to frame.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKdKk.gif

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, you're actually right, and that seems to be the case in most cases but, it wasn't in my case, as you can see in my updated video, I narrowed down the problem and I can see it has to do something with the above text layer's key frames, I don't know why this happens, they're not even overlapping: https://streamable.com/nfzb2b